# RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list' (geopandas)

Tags: python, pandas, runtime-error, geopandas

I'm trying to run this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPoint

df=gpd.read_file('Map.shx')
```

If I run:

```
In [1]:df.crs
Out[2]: {'proj': 'utm', 'zone': 32, 'ellps': 'GRS80', 'units': 'm', 'no_defs': True}
```

Then I impose:

```
df.crs = {'init' :'epsg:4326'}
df=df.to_crs(epsg=4326)
```

to pass to a WGS84 reference system.

But I obtain this error:

```
RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'
```

I don't understand which may be the problem.

Comment: That is an issue with `pyproj` installation. Try to re-install it, if possible from conda-forge. I would also recommend updating GeoPandas itself to 0.7.0 which brings new CRS handling.

Comment: I tried to re-install both from conda-forge, but the latest versions was not updated (GeoPandas version is 0.6.1 and Pyproj is 1.9.6).

Answer (score 0):

You can upgarde both pyproj and geopandas using following commands:

```
pip install pyproj --upgrade 
pip install geopandas --upgrade
```

This will fix it